# Утворення прикметників з числівників та іменників

Tags: граматика, прикметники, числівники

Деякі прикметники, що утворені з числівників мають широке застосування і легко дізнатись як правильно їх писати. Наприклад:
- дводенний;
- трирічний.

Але в деяких випадках виникає потреба у меньш вживаних словах. Щоб не вигадувати сінтетичні приклади надам випадок який мене цікавить безпосередньо. В контексті знакових послідовностей (а саме [кодів Баркера](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)) для опису їх властивостей використовуються слова, що описують їхню довжину. Наприклад: "*п'ятипозиційний*" (код) - це такий код, що має довжину п'ять елементів. Такі слова застосовуються у повсякденному спілкуванні, але чи є вони правильними та чи коректно їх застосовувати у публіцистичних чи наукових текстах? Як правильно писати такі слова? Якщо подивитись на приклади які я навів на початку питання, то виходить, що такі слова треба писати разом. Але як тоді бути наприклад з такими словами: "*двадцятивосьмипозиційний*" (коли лише чисельник складається з декількох слів)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Разом пишемо:
>
> …складні прикметники, першою частиною яких є числівник, написаний літерами: *двадцятиповерхо́вий, семиразо́вий, стовідсотко́вий, стото́нний, двохсотдвадцятип’ятирі́чний*, але *225-рі́чний*;
>
> Через дефіс пишемо:
>
> …складні прикметники, першим компонентом яких є числівник, написаний цифрами: *20-рі́чний, 10-поверхо́вий*.

[Джерело](http://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/32.html).

Comment: `двохсотдвадцятип’ятирі́чний` - так, це мій випадок, дякую!