# Як правильно писати прості числівники — буквами чи цифрами?

Tags: числівники

У словниках і Інтернеті доволі легко знайти правила побудови *складних*¹ числівників та похідних слів.

Але я ніде не зміг знайти правила, яке б регулювало використання **простих числівників**, а саме вибору стосовно того, **буквами чи цифрами** їх записувати.

Наприклад, *«я був там **3** рази»* чи *«я був там **три** рази»*?

Я цілком упевнений, що складні числівники, як-то *42*, мають писатися цифрами, але як щодо простих?

Також, чи правило є різним для використання у різних галузях, як-то ділове листування? *(з очевидних причин, SMS-листування не враховуємо, бо там діє фактор довжини допису)*

---

¹ Джерела, які обговорюють *складні* випадки використання числівників:

- [Утворення прикметників з числівників та іменників](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/88/)
- [Відмінювання числівників](http://l-ponomar.com/vidminyuvannya-chyslivnykiv-chyslivnyky-vorogy-ta-chyslivnyky-druzi/)
- [Написання складаних числівників](http://l-ponomar.com/napysannya-chyslivnykiv-yak-pravylno/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**В загальному випадку можна писати числа і прописом, і цифрами.**

[Написання цифр та символів у ділових паперах](http://studopedia.org/10-86645.html) вказує на таку рекомендацію:

> Числа до десяти варто писати у текстах словами, а піс­ля десяти —
>   цифрами: шість моніторів; 159 школярів.

Для виключення неточностей, приписок неіснуючих цифр в різного виду документах (договорах, бланках, листах, дорученнях тощо), за допомогою яких перераховуються грошові кошти, необхідно прописувати суми повністю.

---

Також, сподіваюсь, вам буде цікаво ознайомитись з деякими іншими правила, що регулють написання слів як прописом, так і в текстовому вигляді.

**Єднальне тире**

Тире ставиться між двома чи кількома словами для позначення діапазону («від… до»):

в) кількісного: *Рукопис обсягом **десять — дванадцять** сторінок* (те ж саме цифрами: **10—12**); Вантаж масою **300—500** кілограмів; **5—7-річна** програма.

Якщо між двома числами, що стоять поруч, можна за змістом вставити не слова «від… до», а слово або (чи), то вони поєднуються дефісом: Буде у відрядженні **п'ять-шість** днів (але при цифровому позначенні ставиться тире: **5—6 днів**).

Тире ставиться між окремими словами для показу внутрішнього зв'язку між ними: Конференція «Архітектура — людина — навколишнє середовище»; Учора — сьогодні — завтра; «Міс Усесвіт — 2006», *«**Повернення Мухтара 1—2**», але «**Мухтар-2**»*.

**Нарощення порядкових числівників**

Якщо порядковий числівник закінчується на приголосну й голосну, у нарощенні відмінкового закінчення пишуться обидві літери, якщо на дві голосні — одна (остання):

- п’ятий — 5-й
- п’ятого — 5-го